# Redirecting from one controller action to another controller action from ajax call

Tags: grails

I am new to grails and I am stuck with the following problem.

I am calling an action1 in  controller1 through an ajax call.
Now though it I want to redirect to  action2 which is in  controller2.

as specified below...  But it doesn't seems to work Please help me!!

```
class controller1 {  
   def action1 = {
       redirect(controller:'controller',action:'action2')
   }
}    

class controller2{  
  action2{

  }
}
```

Comment: it seems an easy example, but I want to be sure: action2 should be def action2 = {...}, right? And the name of controller should be like, for example, UserController.

Answer (score 4):

You need to give the correct controller name for controller attribute

```
redirect(controller:'controller2',action:'action2')
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to do the redirect through your ajax call back function, e.g.:
if you are using JQuery for example

```
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "${createLink(controller:'controller1',action:'action1')}",
           data: "dataToSend="somedata,
           success: function(data){//data is the message rendered from action1
              window.location = ${createLink(controller:'controller2',action:'action2')}
           },
           error: function(){
              alert("Error from controller 1 action 1");
           }
      });
```

in your controller1 action1, you need to render back to the ajax event:

```
class controller1 {  
   def action1 = {
       ........
       some code/logic
       ........
       def message = "some message, success! or error!"
       render(text:message, type:,contentType:'text/xml')
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `render()` instead of `redirect()`.